# Android: Rapid HTTP Requests

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

In my android application I have this bit of code:

```
         while(testCase){
            for(HttpPut put : httpPut){
                try {
                    httpclient.execute(put, responseHandler);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(150);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

My goal is to have a list of pre-built HTTPPut requests (in this case: "httpPut") sent out every 150 miliseconds in order while in a forever loop until told to break (broken by the "testCase" boolean). It works technically, but there sometimes is a lot of lag in the actually execution. On the receiving end of each request, it can lag up to 3-5 seconds before it receives another HTTPPut. And what the phone's screen is shut off its even worse. I am running this code in an extended AsyncTask class.

My question is, what way can I make my code more efficient at executing this code to fire in a more precise manner; to get it as accurately close to every 150 miliseconds as possible? Thanks for reading!

**Edit:**
As recommend to run in another thread, I tried adding this code:

```
...
                performOnBackgroundThread(new Runnable(){

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            final DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            final ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                            httpclient.execute(put, responseHandler);
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });
...

public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } finally {

            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return t;
}
```

But my application quickly crashes with "I/Process(18762): Sending signal. PID: 18762 SIG: 9" and I also get a bunch of these errors.

```
02-10 00:14:58.639: W/SingleClientConnManager(18762): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
02-10 00:14:58.639: W/SingleClientConnManager(18762): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
02-10 00:14:58.639: W/SingleClientConnManager(18762): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
02-10 00:14:58.639: W/SingleClientConnManager(18762): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
02-10 00:14:58.647: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
02-10 00:14:58.655: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
02-10 00:14:58.655: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
02-10 00:14:58.655: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
02-10 00:14:58.655: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
02-10 00:14:58.655: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at com.<takenout>.<takenout>.<takenout>.run(MyFile.java:79)
02-10 00:14:58.663: W/System.err(18762):    at com.<takenout>.<takenout>.<takenout>.run(MyFile.java:116)
02-10 00:14:58.671: W/System.err(18762): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
02-10 00:14:58.671: W/System.err(18762):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
02-10 00:14:58.671: W/System.err(18762):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-10 00:14:58.671: W/dalvikvm(18762): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d03300)
```

**Edit #2:**

```
02-10 00:38:08.639: W/System.err(20100): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-10 00:38:08.639: W/System.err(20100):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
02-10 00:38:08.639: W/System.err(20100):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
02-10 00:38:08.639: W/System.err(20100):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at com.<takenout>.<takenout>.<takenout>.run(MyFile.java:79)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at com.<takenout>.<takenout>.<takenout>.run(MyFile.java:116)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
02-10 00:38:08.647: W/System.err(20100):    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You really can't 100% guarantee that your server will see an updated every 150ms, due to variance in network metrics. Your best bet is to try for something faster than what you want e.g. send a new request out every 100ms and hope that the server receives an update at least every 100ms. Moreover, if you are sending requests this quickly, consider using UDP over TCP. TCP requests take much longer in my experience due to overhead of ensuring that a packet is delivered, but if you loose one or two it's not a huge deal for you if your average case performance is much better e.g. 90% of the time you see updates every 100ms.

You are likely seeing delays on the server currently because you are running into earlier requests e.g. if req1 takes 200ms, req2 takes 350ms, and req3 takes 120ms, then on the server you won't be seeing requests every 150ms. This is particularly true of the first few requests, where the network performance may be substantially worse (e.g. 1-2 seconds) then after 5-10 requests.

I would recommend creating a second AsyncTask class that you rapidly spawn off of the first AsyncTask (see [this](http://code.google.com/p/vtnetapps/source/browse/trunk/assignments/Alex_Corvin/HttpUtility/src/org/vt/http/utility/AsyncHttpRequest.java) for some potential guidance). However, this might only get you so far as you will eventually run into some threading limits if you're generating new request objects so quickly.

The big question is are you sure you're doing the right thing? You are not letting the network chipset sleep much at all with a 150ms gap between requests (which likely take longer than 150ms to complete execution!), so why even bother with many individual requests? Why not use something like a socket that stays open (perhaps google http long polling for examples)?

Comment: Thank you for the really thought out response! Unfortunately, I don't have control over the receiving end at all, so I don't think I could modify just my end to make UDP over TCP work (unless I'm wrong, I am not familiar with it that well).

Luckily, the receiver is on the same network as my phone, so the ping in ms should be very low, right? It makes sense that my phone could screw up because the process to sleep takes longer than the 150ms timeframe itself. If it is any interest, there is an iPhone equivalent of this app that is able to fire the 150ms request on my same network dead on.